# Blur Effect when push button

Tags: ios, swift3, blur

I want to use blur effect in my view's background in viewcontroller  But some times it doesn't work and when it works it won't work properly and 
when I run the program on the big screed devices like iPad there is an black square on the top and I can't see The blur effect

here is my code

```
class sahafiViewController: UIViewController , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate {




@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImg: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurView.frame = backgroundImg.bounds
    backgroundImg.addSubview(blurView)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}}
```

[here is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg1iK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try your code in viewDidAppear method.

Comment: doesn't work :( The page won't be blur it will be completely black!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
     super.viewDidLoad()

     let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
     let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

     blurView.frame =  CGRect(x: self. backgroundImg.frame.origin.x, y: self. backgroundImg.frame.origin.y, width: self. backgroundImg.frame.size.width, height: self. backgroundImg.frame.size.height)

     blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

     self.backgroundImg.addSubview(blurView)
}
```

Comment: I don't know why ! But It worked in small iPhone But in the bigger screen devices like iPhone plus and iPad the screen will be gray in the light blur and black in the dark blur!

Comment: I would suggest you to check the frame given to the backgroundImg. The frame should be correctly given then, it will work.

Comment: I checked that it is ok and I used these codes in another view controller in another class and it didn't work so the problem is code

Comment: I am using this code and there is no issue. Could you please confirm the frame given to the backgroundImg?

Comment: what do you mean "confirm the frame given to the background"?